# How to combine several objects into one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

When I'm doing http request, I'm getting the array of objects, for example:

```
 [ 
  { row: '3', col: '1', val: '10:00' },
  { row: '3', col: '2', val: 'Some text' },
  { row: '3', col: '3', val: 'Yura' },
  { row: '3', col: '4', val: '676031383' },

  { row: '3', col: '6', val: '9:00 ' },
  { row: '3', col: '7', val: 'Some text' },
  { row: '3', col: '8', val: 'Alex' },
  { row: '3', col: '9', val: '965773775' },

  { row: '4', col: '1', val: '7:00' },
  { row: '4', col: '2', val: 'Some text' },
  { row: '4', col: '3', val: 'Anya' },
  { row: '4', col: '4', val: '951018689' },

  { row: '4', col: '6', val: '08:00' },
  { row: '4', col: '7', val: 'Some text' },
  { row: '4', col: '8', val: 'Dima' },
  { row: '4', col: '9', val: '961452584' },
]
```

The problem is I need to combine these objects into the one and add one more key - **type**, for example:

```
{ time: 10:00, info: 'Some text', name: 'Yura', phone: '676031383', type: 'Driver' }

{ time: 9:00, info: 'Some text', name: 'Alex', phone: '965773775', type: 'Passenger' }

{ time: 7:00, info: 'Some text', name: 'Anya', phone: '951018689', type: 'Driver' }

{ time: 8:00, info: 'Some text', name: 'Dima', phone: '951018689', type: 'Passenger' }
```

From `1` to `4` type should be "Driver", from `6` to `9` should be "Passenger".
Response does not have 5 column because she is empty

Is it possible to do this somehow? I spent several hours, but without results

Comment: Yes, that's possible. What did you try, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Where did you get the type is 'Driver' or 'Passenger'?

Comment: The aboe object is already one.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed I'm writing it's just manually, Or it's could be some constants.

Comment: But if you don't know where it comes from then how to figure it out?

Comment: And is it always follow the order you show?

Comment: I've updated post. And yes it always follow the order. after `9  col` will be `1 col`, but `row ` will be 4

Comment: are there exactly 36 objects in the array (4 x 9)?

Comment: Where is column 5? Because from what Im understanding every 4th column you will have a complete object

Comment: @Charlie 5 column i need to skip, because she is empty

Comment: If you know what maps to what.. then look at this https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d

Comment: What should be the type of the rest of the objects? An empty string `""`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir By rest you mean, row and col?  They should be skipped

Comment: No. You said _from 1 to 4 type should be "Driver", from 6 to 9 should be "Passenger"_. What about the rest like **0**, **5** and **>9**?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir You should start from 3 row. 5 just empty, and 9 it's  max number

Comment: You should've posted the array as is. The question is so vage now. So each array that comes from the response contains exactly 9 objects (no more, no less), and you want to group the first 4 as one object of type `driver` and skip over the 5th object and group the last 4 as one object of type passenger. Right?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir There is only one array, but  he has a lof of objects. I just didn’t want to do a large array as an example. And yes i want to group from 1 to 4 column into one object and give a type `driver`. From 6 to 9 give type `passenger` And just forget about 5 column, because in the response 
I do not get it him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, that's what you've been after:

```js
const src = [{row:'3',col:'1',val:'10:00'},{row:'3',col:'2',val:'Some text'},{row:'3',col:'3',val:'Yura'},{row:'3',col:'4',val:'676031383'},{row:'3',col:'6',val:'9:00 '},{row:'3',col:'7',val:'Some text'},{row:'3',col:'8',val:'Alex'},{row:'3',col:'9',val:'965773775'},{row:'4',col:'1',val:'7:00'},{row:'4',col:'2',val:'Some text'},{row:'4',col:'3',val:'Anya'},{row:'4',col:'4',val:'951018689'},{row:'4',col:'6',val:'08:00'},{row:'4',col:'7',val:'Some text'},{row:'4',col:'8',val:'Dima'},{row:'4',col:'9',val:'961452584'},],

      res = [...src]
        .reduceRight((r,i,_,s) => (r.push(s.splice(0,4)),r),[])
        .map((e,i) => ({time: e[0].val, info: e[1].val, name:e[2].val, phone: e[3].val, type: i&1 ? 'Passenger' : 'Driver'}))

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i needed, would be better if you rename your variables for better understanding.

Comment: @ЛюбчикКочан : *longer* variable names will not make more sense, you may simply inquiry [`Array.prototype.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) reference to sort things out.

Comment: @ЛюбчикКочан : another point - consider updated version of above solution if you don't want your source array to get mutated

Comment: Small note – make sure the array is sorted to avoid mixup 
`[...src].sort((a,b)=>a.col-b.col).sort((a,b)=>a.row-b.row)`

Answer (score 0):

I've rearranged the output format as you can easily grab your required data to manipulate. Here I attach the code. Please feel free to comment if it does not meet your requirements.

```js
const data = [ 
 { row: '3', col: '1', val: '10:00' },
 { row: '3', col: '2', val: 'Some text' },
 { row: '3', col: '3', val: 'Yura' },
 { row: '3', col: '4', val: '676031383' },
  
 { row: '3', col: '6', val: '9:00 ' },
 { row: '3', col: '7', val: 'Some text' },
 { row: '3', col: '8', val: 'Alex' },
 { row: '3', col: '9', val: '965773775' },

 { row: '4', col: '1', val: '10:00' },
 { row: '4', col: '2', val: 'Some text' },
 { row: '4', col: '3', val: 'Yura' },
 { row: '4', col: '4', val: '676031383' },
  
 { row: '4', col: '6', val: '9:00 ' },
 { row: '4', col: '7', val: 'Some text' },
 { row: '4', col: '8', val: 'Alex' },
 { row: '4', col: '9', val: '965773775' },
];

const result = {}
data.forEach(v => result[v.row] = {driver: {}, passenger: {}});

data.forEach(value => {
 if (value.col === '1')      result[value.row].driver.time = value.val;
 else if (value.col === '2') result[value.row].driver.info = value.val;
 else if (value.col === '3') result[value.row].driver.name = value.val;
 else if (value.col === '4') result[value.row].driver.phone = value.val;
 else if (value.col === '6') result[value.row].passenger.time = value.val;
 else if (value.col === '7') result[value.row].passenger.info = value.val;
 else if (value.col === '8') result[value.row].passenger.name = value.val;
 else if (value.col === '9') result[value.row].passenger.phone = value.val;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Suggested solution almost right, but you are combining two objects into one, but needed just separate.
On the other side solution quite bad because what if there are 100 columns? So there will be the same number of conditon?

Comment: I arrange in this format as it will easy to retrieve data. It will group the data row-wise and type-wise. And you said after col 9 this will start col 1 and change the row number.